# In SQL, Trying to link 2 tables, adding missing lines for current month only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert data into a table from the following table and view.
The script will be run on the last day of the month and will insert this info into SqFtByMonth.  I believe it has something to do with my WHERE clause.  There are 6 warehouses in WarehouseBaseSqFt and not all Warehouses are in StorageUsageConesMonthly every month.  I am trying to build a table that would give me a line for each warehouse for each month when the script is run at the end of the month.  With my current code I am only receiving a line for each Warehouse in the StorageUsageConesMonthly View.

```
TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseBaseSqFt](
[Warehouse] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[WarehouseName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TotalSqFt] [int] NOT NULL,
[UsableSqFt] [int] NOT NULL,
[GLDept] [int] NULL

VIEW [dbo].[StorageUsageConesMonthly] AS
SELECT TOP 1000 [COUNTYEAR]
  ,[COUNTMONTH]
  ,[IDWHSE]
  ,[GLDept]
  ,[IDLOCATION]
  ,[IDCUST]
  ,[PltQtyPerMonth]
  ,[DaysOccupied]
  ,[DaysInMonth]
  ,CAST(PltQtyPerMonth /DaysInMonth * 17.33333 / 2 AS decimal (8,4))AS SqFtUtilized


INSERT INTO [dbo].[SqFtByMonth] ([Warehouse],[CountYear],[CountMonth],[TotalSqFt],[BaseUsableSqFt] ,[ConeSqFt] ,[UsableSqFtForMonth])
SELECT  CASE WHEN sucm.IDWHSE IS NULL THEN wbs.Warehouse
            ELSE sucm.IDWHSE
    END AS  Warehsoue,
    YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),
    MONTH(SYSDATETIME())-1,
    wbs.TotalSqFt,
    wbs.UsableSqFt,
    CASE WHEN SUM(sucm.SqFtUtilized) is null THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(sucm.SqFtUtilized)
    END AS ConeSqFt,
    CASE WHEN SUM(sucm.SqFtUtilized) is null THEN wbs.UsableSqFt
            ELSE wbs.UsableSqFt + SUM(sucm.SqFtUtilized) 
    END AS UsableSqFtForMonth 
FROM [dbo].[StorageUsageConesMonthly] sucm

full outer JOIN [dbo].[WarehouseBaseSqFt] wbs
ON wbs.Warehouse = sucm.IDWHSE
  WHERE sucm.COUNTYEAR = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND sucm.COUNTMONTH =  MONTH(SYSDATETIME())
GROUP BY sucm.COUNTYEAR,
    sucm.COUNTMONTH,
    sucm.IDWHSE,
    wbs.Warehouse,
    wbs.TotalSqFt,
    wbs.UsableSqFt


    ORDER BY Warehouse
```

Thanks for your help in advance,
Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `WHERE` clause is the cause of the problem. For warehouses that do not have a record at `StorageUsageConesMonthly`, `sucm.COUNTYEAR` and `sucm.COUNTMONTH` are also `NULL`. When you use them in `WHERE` clause they do not match with the current year and month and these warehouses do not exist in the output.

I'm guessing you want to this data from only this month. Then a CTE might help

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[StorageUsageConesMonthly] sucm
    WHERE sucm.COUNTYEAR = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND sucm.COUNTMONTH =  MONTH(SYSDATETIME())
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SqFtByMonth] ([Warehouse],[CountYear],[CountMonth],[TotalSqFt],[BaseUsableSqFt] ,[ConeSqFt] ,[UsableSqFtForMonth])
SELECT  CASE WHEN CTE.IDWHSE IS NULL THEN wbs.Warehouse
        ELSE CTE.IDWHSE
END AS  Warehsoue,
        YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),
        MONTH(SYSDATETIME())-1,
        wbs.TotalSqFt,
        wbs.UsableSqFt,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CTE.SqFtUtilized) is null THEN 0
                ELSE SUM(CTE.SqFtUtilized)
        END AS ConeSqFt,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CTE.SqFtUtilized) is null THEN wbs.UsableSqFt
                ELSE wbs.UsableSqFt + SUM(CTE.SqFtUtilized) 
        END AS UsableSqFtForMonth 
FROM CTE full outer JOIN [dbo].[WarehouseBaseSqFt] wbs
        ON wbs.Warehouse = CTE.IDWHSE    
GROUP BY CTE.COUNTYEAR,
         CTE.COUNTMONTH,
         CTE.IDWHSE,
         wbs.Warehouse,
         wbs.TotalSqFt,
         wbs.UsableSqFt
```

This might not be exactly what you want but I guess it is sufficient to demonstrate the idea. Do not filter with `WHERE` in a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Instead first filter the tables individually, then do the join.

Also you don't need to use CTE, you can achieve the same result with placing the CTE query as a nested query inside the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: The select works fine, but when I run the entire script with the insert I received the error message above.

Comment: I made a typo due to copy paste, I've corrected it now. Insert should follow CTE expression.

Comment: I got it thanks,  moved the insert  to just above the select statement